# Mixed Content Still Blocked in Chrome 118.0.5993.70 Despite Allowing Insecure Content

Tags: google-chrome, internet-radio, mixed-content

I'm encountering a mixed content blocking issue in Google Chrome (Version 118.0.5993.70) even after setting "Insecure Content" to "Allow" in site settings. The problem persists as (blocked:mixed-content) in the developer tools.

Context: Many Internet radio stations use non-secure URLs for broadcasting, which are often linked from secure websites. Allowing mixed content for these sites was expected to resolve the issue, but the content (radio streams) remains blocked.

Example Sites:

- https://directory.shoutcast.com/
- https://www.internet-radio.com/

Is anyone else experiencing this issue with Chrome, or is there a known workaround?